# Using Python multiprocessing library inside nested objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.6

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing library to parallelize some expensive calculations without blocking some others, much lighter. The both need to interact through some variables, although the may run with different paces.

To show this, I have created the following example, that works fine:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import numpy as np


class SumClass:

    def __init__(self):

        self.result = 0.0
        self.p = None
        self.return_value = None

    def expensive_function(self, new_number, return_value):

        # Execute expensive calculation
        #######
        time.sleep(np.random.random_integers(5, 10, 1))
        return_value.value = self.result + new_number
        #######

    def execute_function(self, new_number):

        print(' New number received: %f' % new_number)
        self.return_value = multiprocessing.Value("f", 0.0, lock=True)
        self.p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.expensive_function, args=(new_number, self.return_value))
        self.p.start()

    def is_executing(self):

        if self.p is not None:

            if not self.p.is_alive():
                self.result = self.return_value.value
                self.p = None
                return False

            else:
                return True

        else:
            return False


if __name__ == '__main__':

    sum_obj = SumClass()
    current_value = 0

    while True:

        if not sum_obj.is_executing():

            # Randomly determine whether the function must be executed or not
            if np.random.rand() < 0.25:
                print('Current sum value: %f' % sum_obj.result)
                new_number = np.random.rand(1)[0]
                sum_obj.execute_function(new_number)

        # Execute other (light) stuff
        #######
        print('Executing other stuff')
        current_value += sum_obj.result * 0.1
        print('Current value: %f' % current_value)
        time.sleep(1)
        #######
```

Basically, in the main loop some light function is executed, and depending on a random condition, some heavy work is sent to another process if it has already finished the previous one, carried out by an object which **needs** to store some data between executions. Although *expensive_function* needs some time, the light function keeps on executing without being blocked.

Although the above code gets the job done, I'm wondering: **is it the best/most appropriate method to do this?**

Besides, let us suppose the class SumClass has an instance of another object, which also needs to store data. For example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import numpy as np


class Operator:

    def __init__(self):

        self.last_value = 1.0

    def operate(self, value):

        print('    Operation, last value: %f' % self.last_value)
        self.last_value *= value
        return self.last_value


class SumClass:

    def __init__(self):

        self.operator_obj = Operator()
        self.result = 0.0

        self.p = None
        self.return_value = None

    def expensive_function(self, new_number, return_value):

        # Execute expensive calculation
        #######
        time.sleep(np.random.random_integers(5, 10, 1))

        # Apply operation
        number = self.operator_obj.operate(new_number)

        # Apply other operation
        return_value.value = self.result + number
        #######

    def execute_function(self, new_number):

        print('    New number received: %f' % new_number)
        self.return_value = multiprocessing.Value("f", 0.0, lock=True)
        self.p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.expensive_function, args=(new_number, self.return_value))
        self.p.start()

    def is_executing(self):
        if self.p is not None:
            if not self.p.is_alive():
                self.result = self.return_value.value
                self.p = None
                return False
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return False


if __name__ == '__main__':

    sum_obj = SumClass()
    current_value = 0

    while True:

        if not sum_obj.is_executing():

            # Randomly determine whether the function must be executed or not
            if np.random.rand() < 0.25:
                print('Current sum value: %f' % sum_obj.result)
                new_number = np.random.rand(1)[0]
                sum_obj.execute_function(new_number)

        # Execute other (light) stuff
        #######
        print('Executing other stuff')
        current_value += sum_obj.result * 0.1
        print('Current value: %f' % current_value)
        time.sleep(1)
        #######
```

Now, inside the *expensive_function*, a function member of the object *Operator* is used, which needs to store the number passed.

As expected, the member variable *last_value* does not change, i.e. it does not keep any value.

**Is there any way of doing this properly?**

I can imagine I could arrange everything so that I only need to use one class level, and it would work well. However, this is a toy example, in reality there are different levels of complex objects and it would be hard.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is this on a unix-like system or windows? On a spawning system like windows, `multiprocessing.Process(target=self.expensive_function,...)` pickles/unpickles `self` which can get expensive. It may be better to run through a static function instead. This is most just a side comment.

Comment: Its hard to say from the example but if you want to keep state across the subprocess runs, it may be better to run that process once and use a queue to pass data back and forth. Even a Pool with a single process and `apply_async`, which implements the queue for you, could be good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm running it in Ubuntu 18.04. I will try to modify everything so that everything related to the expensive function is implemented as a static function. 
I wonder if there is any way to run the main function in a process and the SumClass instance in another (a loop-like function that would wait for a input to run the expensive operation). Normally I would use ROS (Robot Operating System), communicating both processes using topics or services.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from numba import jit
import requests
import timeit


def timer(number, repeat):
    def wrapper(func):
        runs = timeit.repeat(func, number=number, repeat=repeat)
        print(sum(runs) / len(runs))
    return wrapper


URL = "https://httpbin.org/uuid"

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True,cache=True)
def fetch(session, url):
    with session.get(url) as response:
        print(response.json()['uuid'])


@timer(1, 1)
def runner():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=25) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            executor.map(fetch, [session] * 100, [URL] * 100)
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
            executor._adjust_thread_count
```

Maybe this might help.

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor for multithreading. you can also use ProcessPoolExecutor.

For your compute expensive operation you can use numba for making cached byte code of your function for faster exeution.